# Why is `Properties` not a valid field name in ksql?

Tags: ksqldb

https://docs.confluent.io/5.4.1/ksql/docs/developer-guide/syntax-reference.html#struct-overview Confluent docs say they don't accept `Properties` as a valid field name, but why?

What if I do have a schema with `Properties`, what can I do then?

Comment: It's a [keyword/reserved word](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/reference/sql/appendix/) in the language. I'm not familiar with ksql specifically, but most sql distributions provide backticks to escape references for this reason (and more). Without those, it'd make sense you couldn't use it.

Comment: Makes sense. I could escape it with backticks!

Comment: @Rogue, do you want to put your comment as an answer?  If you do so, we can upvote it!

Comment: I suppose I can. I have a lot of comments that are like that, heh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [keyword/reserved word](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/reference/sql/appendix/) in the language. I'm not familiar with ksql specifically, but most sql distributions provide backticks to escape references for this reason (and more). Without those, it'd make sense you couldn't use it.

As an example of using backticks in a pretty standard sql statement:

```
SELECT `table`.`properties` FROM `table` ...
```